# Read from CSV file to List of objects

Tags: c#

I need to read this CSV file and convert it to `List<Vehicle>` of objects (cars and bicycles), first row must be ignored and 3rd value is type of object:

```
Name price typeOfVehicle Horsepower NumberOfPedals
Audi,100000,Car,500,
BMW,20000,Car,300
Abici,1000,Bicycle,,2
Atala,2000,Bicycle,,2
```

My code so far:

```
abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }

    class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public int Horsepower { get; set; }
    }

    class Bicycle : Vehicle
    {
        public int NumberOfPedals { get; set; }
    }

    static class Offers
    {
        public  List<Vehicle> itemlist = new List<Vehicle>();
        public static void readfromfile()
        {
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Offers.csv");

            foreach (string item in lines)
            {
                var values = item.Split(',');
                //need to check which type of vehicle is it
                if (values[2] == "Car")
                {
                    itemlist.Add(new Car()
                    {
                        Name = values[0],
                        Price = int.Parse(values[1]),
                        Horsepower = int.Parse(values[3])
                    });
                }
                else if (values[2] == "Bicycle")
                {
                    itemlist.Add(new Bicycle()
                    {
                        Name = values[0],
                        Price = int.Parse(values[1]),
                        NumberOfPedals = int.Parse(values[3])
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I want to read from CSV file, when reading it I need to check for each line if 3rd value is car or bicycle. If it is a car then I make car object (and give it all values to properties) and put it in the list of Vehicles and same for bicycle.

I'm getting this error for `itemlist`:

> an object reference is required for the nonstatic field 'Offers.itemlist

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

```
abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }

    class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public int Horsepower { get; set; }
    }

    class Bicycle : Vehicle
    {
        public int NumberOfPedals { get; set; }
    }

    static class Offers
    {
        public static List<Vehicle> itemlist = new List<Vehicle>();
        public static void readfromfile()
        {
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Offers.csv").Skip(1).TakeWhile(t => t != null);

            foreach (string item in lines)
            {
                var values = item.Split(',');
                //need to check which type of vehicle is it
                if (values[2] == "Car")
                {
                    itemlist.Add(new Car()
                    {
                        Name = values[0],
                        Price = int.Parse(values[1]),
                        Horsepower = int.Parse(values[3])
                    });
                }
                else if (values[2] == "Bicycle")
                {
                    itemlist.Add(new Bicycle()
                    {
                        Name = values[0],
                        Price = int.Parse(values[1]),
                        NumberOfPedals = int.Parse(values[3])
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: As it looks, your code is only missing the explicit "skip header line" requirement.

Comment: This seems more like a progress report than a question

Comment: Actually it is missing more then that, it is not working for me at all at the moment and I dont know what I did wrong

Comment: @Damjan25 You need to explain exactly *how* it is not working. Where does it fail? What are the symptoms?

Comment: "It is not working for me" does not explain the problem. It's just a status update. Also, please refrain from using txtspk. Twitter is elsewhere (or whatever social chat app is "in" these days)

Comment: I'm getting this error for itemlist: an object reference is required for the non static field 'Offers.itemlist

Comment: @Damjan25 That is very important information. You need to add it to your question.

Comment: @Damjan25, do not edit the question to contain the solution. Part of the question are the actual programming mistakes, warts and all,  right? The question without these mistakes does not make much sense anymore. If somebody looks at your question now, they will have a hard time to connect the answers with your question.

Comment: Yes, I know but final solution is from multiple answers below. I think it will be easier to understand if I combine answers into solution

Comment: @Damjan25, like you did it now is not bad :)

Comment: You could just add your own answer with the "final solution" that draws from the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you did wrong was you were adding objects of type "item" to itemlist instead of the car or bycycle you declared on the line above.

Another issue found was that originally there was no static modifier on your list declaration. Without it, you need an instance (i.e. not static) of your class. To make this class instanciable, you would need to remove the static modifers from the class, all its fields, properties and methods.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

```
static class Offers
{
    public static List<Vehicle> itemlist = new List<Vehicle>();
    public static void readfromfile()
    {
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Offers.csv");

        foreach (string item in lines)
        {
            var values = item.Split(',');
            //need to check which type of vehicle is it
            if(values[2] == "Car")
            {
                itemlist.Add(new Car()
                {
                    Name = values[0],
                    Price = int.Parse(values[1]),
                    Horsepower = int.Parse(values[3])
                });
            }
            else if (values[2]=="Bicycle")
            {
                itemlist.Add(new Bicycle()
                {
                    Name = values[0],
                    Price = int.Parse(values[1]),
                    NumberOfPedals= int.Parse(values[3])
                });
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where should i declare  public List<Vehicle> itemlist = new List<Vehicle>(); ? beacuse at the moment I am getting this error:  an object reference is required for the non static field 'Offers.itemlist

Comment: public List<Vehicle> itemlist = new List<Vehicle>() should be public static List<Vehicle> itemlist = new List<Vehicle>();

Comment: Perhaps add this bit of information about the missing static modifier to your answer, since it is crucial to the solution of the problem ;) (While it is already in your source code, it could easily be overlooked when just skimming the answer)

Comment: Nitpicking :) The explanation with regard to the static modifier is a bit unfortunate and incorrect. Even with an instance of Offers it would not work without the static modifier. The reason is the readfromfile() method being a static method. And you cannot use a non-static member in a static method (the method remains static even if you create an instance of Offers) I guess you wanted to say "non-static method" instead of "non-static class".

Comment: Definitely nitpicky. I guess i was thinking to make it an instanciable class one would remove the static modifers but i can see how that might be useful to someone misusing the static modifer. will change

Comment: No, sorry. Now i am not nitpicky anymore :P. The way you explained it now is simply wrong. To make a class instantiable you do not need to remove all static members or change them into instance members. There are classes everywhere that can both be instanced while also having static members. I get the feeling that somewhere, somehow you misunderstand the static modifier in some way...

Comment: Please see microsofts opening statement:

A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there is one difference: a static class cannot be instantiated. In other words, you cannot use the new keyword to create a variable of the class type. Because there is no instance variable, you access the members of a static class by using the class name itself.

Comment: You misunderstood this statement. Read it again.

Comment: This statement is only about the class itself being static or non-static. It is your wrong assumption that a non-static class cannot have static memebers. Read what you wrote in your answer: "To make a class instanciable, you would need to remove the static modifers from the class, **all its fields, properties and methods**." The emphasized part is utter nonsense.

Comment: Changed "To make a class" to "to make this class" so my answer is specific to his example and avoid having to explain each the million possible computations of mixed modifiers

Answer (score 2):

Your current code creates a new Bike / Car object but then never uses it. Instead you've been calling: new item() which is not a valid type/class in your program. Populate each of the objects properties before adding the Bike/ Car object to the list of Vehicle objects.

```
Vehicle car = new Car();
car.Name = values[0];
car.Price = int.Parse(values[1]);
car.Horsepower = int.Parse(values[3]);
itemlist.Add(car);
```

Comment: I have retracted my -1 now, as you put effort into giving a meaningful answer. Just an FYI (meant as a correction, not criticism): You said "is not a valid object". What you certainly meant was "is not a valid type/class" (objects and types are quite different)

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is marking your class `Offer` and your method `readfromfile()` as `static`. If you have no specific reason, just remove the `static` modifiers and your issue is solved.

---

There are 2 options for solving your second issue (Index out of bounds):

1) Add the delimiter `,` to your column header line:

```
Name,price,typeOfVehicle,Horsepower,NumberOfPedals
```

2) Skip the column header line before splitting your lines:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Offers.csv").Skip(1);
```

Comment: What is this part for? : .TakeWhile(t => t != null)

Comment: It takes all lines until there are no more. (after skiping the first line) but that's not needed indeed.